# Почему при нажатии на две кнопки у меня не закрывается окно?

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5, pyqt

При зажатии клавиш D + Ctrl должно закрываться окно,но этого не происходит.

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_D + Qt.CTRL:
    # Тестил и такое: 
    # if event.key() == Qt.Key_D and Qt.CTRL:
        self.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Потомучто `Ctrl` надо проверять в `event.modifiers()`

Comment: ```Qt.Key_H + Qt.ControlModifier``` правильно понял?

Comment: @Иван https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/101689/PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier тут пример 3

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *

class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.keymap = {}
        for key, value in vars(Qt).items():
            if isinstance(value, Qt.Key):
                self.keymap[value] = key.partition('_')[2]

        self.modmap = {
            Qt.ControlModifier: self.keymap[Qt.Key_Control],
            Qt.AltModifier:     self.keymap[Qt.Key_Alt],
            Qt.ShiftModifier:   self.keymap[Qt.Key_Shift],
            Qt.MetaModifier:    self.keymap[Qt.Key_Meta],
            Qt.GroupSwitchModifier: self.keymap[Qt.Key_AltGr],
            Qt.KeypadModifier:  self.keymap[Qt.Key_NumLock],
            }

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    def keyevent_to_string(self, event):
        sequence = []
        for modifier, text in self.modmap.items():
            if event.modifiers() & modifier:
                sequence.append(text)
        key = self.keymap.get(event.key(), event.text())
        if key not in sequence:
            sequence.append(key)
        return '+'.join(sequence)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print(self.keyevent_to_string(event))

        self.label.setText(self.keyevent_to_string(event))

#        if event.key() == 68: #Qt.Key_D + Qt.CTRL:
        if self.keyevent_to_string(event) == "Control+D":
            self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]